# Copying animation (action) to different object doesn't animate bones

Tags: animation, actions

I'm trying to play back an animation on a different object that has an identical rig to the original object (same bone structure, same names and everything - the relative positions of the bones are a bit different, but not too much either).

The original object is an imported .bvh motion capture file and shows its action (141_13) in the action editor, which plays back fine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QERtw.png

I add the second object, a MakeHuman model with an identical rig, and assign the action of the imported .bvh object, and it looks like this (a lot more going on than in the original screenshot):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/osgiX.jpg

But the action doesn't animate the new object's bones. The location of the entire object seems to shift around in sync with the original .bvh animation somewhat, but as you can see to a totally different locations, and the actual bones don't move at all, it stays in that T-pose looking stance all the way through.

I was under the impression that if two objects have the same armature, you should be able to just assign actions from one object to the other. Am I missing something?

I've uploaded a small project containing the above on google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/180BfTwDi8emW5mhIPt8Ve_0d7pvyU4qx?usp=sharing

Comment: If everything is setup correctly it should work. Hard to tell what's wrong, I think you'll have to upload your file.

Comment: @joshsanfelici Probably a good idea. I added a google drive link containing the project to the question.